# Change node display for purchased products

Tags: 7, views, commerce, theming, panels

I am using Drupal 7 and [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), and i want to change the appearance of product display node when a user bought the product which he references.

For example :

**1/** Product display before having been bought : title, teaser, price, add to cart form

**2/** Product display having been bought : title, teaser, body

I try [the solution](https://drupalcommerce.org/videos/tutorials/selling-pernode-access-drupal-commerce) giving by Commerce Guys, but I don't want to create two nodes (product display and paid content).

Would you have a solution?

Comment: This is a bit confusing as the solution you reference is about selling the ability to create nodes as opposed to having a product that someone can by and then displaying that someone has purchased it. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: thanks nvahalik for your time. The solution i reference is about selling per-node access, not the ability to create nodes. Otherwise, I try to find a simple solution of pay-per-view/paywall : If the user didn't buy the product, he sees title/teaser/add to cart form, if he bought it, he sees the full content of that page.

Comment: This goes out into the realm of a HOWTO which goes beyond Drupal SE's guidelines.

Comment: Hm, I don't know if it's my bad english which makes that I'm badly understood, but i only ask what is the best way to display only the teaser of a node which the product it references was not bought... Only the way (views or other), i don't think this question is out of Drupal Answers requirements